# Finding the modulus of a complex number that satisfies a polynomial relation

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z^2-2z+3=0.$ Find the modulus of $$f(z)=z^{17}-z^{15}+6z^{14}+3z^2-5z+9$$

> **My attempt:**
>   $z^2-2z+3=0\Leftrightarrow\left[ \begin{array}{l}z=1+\sqrt{2}i\\z=1-\sqrt{2}i\end{array}\right.$
>
> We have: $f(z)=\left(z^2\right)^7\times z^2-\left(z^2\right)^7\times z+6\left(z^2\right)^7+3z^2-5z+9\\=\left(z^2\right)^7\left[z^2-z+6\right]+3z^2-5z+9$

I do not know how to continue, please help me.

Comment: What is the correct equation $z^2-3z+3=0$ or $z^2-2z+3=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by find the modulo ?

Comment: Unless you are paying for internet service by the amount of letters you type, **PLEASE** use actual words, and not internet shortcuts.

Comment: I'm Vietnamese so I don't know how to present my thought in English :(

Comment: Surely you know that "plz" is not actual English.

Comment: I am sorry, i will write "plase" for "plz" the next times.

Comment: I am sorry, I have just edit my Question, please see it again.

Comment: Even if you don't notice Fabien's "trick", a quadratic is readily computible. Note that $(1+\sqrt{2}i)^2 = (1-2) + 2\sqrt{2}i = -1 + 2\sqrt{2}$ and that $(z^{*})^2 = (z^2)^{*}$ where $*$ denotes the conjugate. You should get $\sqrt{3}$ as a result as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: use polynomial division to write

$$f(z) = z^{17}-z^{15}+6z^{14}+3z^{2}-5z+9 = q(z)(z^{2}-2z+3) + r(z)$$

Since $z^{2}-2z+3 = 0$, then we have $f(z) = r(z)$. Since $r(z)$ should be linear in $z$, it should be easy to find the modulus from there. Feel free to comment if you need more help.

Comment: Using computer assistance we get $r(z)=2630z-3354$, which would not be very pleasant to find by hand.  I wonder if there is a clever trick in this particular case?

Comment: I am sorry, I have just edit my Question, please see it again.

Comment: @ILoveMath: the method is the same, just replace $f(z)$ with what you have written. David: hrmmm, good point. Let's see if the updated polynomial comes out cleaner.

Comment: @David: with computer assistance (see http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f396eaca9aaccbf858652bccc972324a) on the new polynomial, the result is much nicer, with $r(z)= z$, confirming Fabien's result. However, I think Fabien's clever observation is probably cleaner. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here $z$ is such as $z^2-2z+3=0$
$$3(z^2-2z+3)=0 \;\; so\;\;3z^2-5z+9 = z$$
$$z^{17}=2z^{16}-3z^{15}=2(2z^{15}-3z^{14})-3z^{15}=z^{15}-6z^{14}$$
so$$f(z)=z$$